# Sitecore Content Editor breaks when opening a specific item in a specific language

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7, machinekey

I am facing this weird error in a live Sitecore instance.

It is multi-language, english and french. It has over a thousand content items.

With two items(that is what we found so far) I am having this problem.

I am able to open the item in its english version but when I try to switch language to french nothing happens. If I select any other item, switch to French, and then try to open this problematic item, Content Editor breaks and stop responding.

This error is being logged in Sitecore`s log:

```
4236 12:00:36 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
4236 12:00:36 ERROR Could not decrypt value85953F0F(...trimmed...)B2A
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Unable to validate data.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData)
   at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket)
   at Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.GetSavedUser(String cookieName)
```

Does anybody have a suggestion of what is happening or what I might try to solve it?

Using Fiddler, I also saw that the POST and RESPONSE are ok, like any other language switch on items.

Also tried to use "Raw Values", and it still breaking my content editor.

Really appreciate any help, tks

Comment: Is the content manually entered or have you used some kind of an import script ?

Comment: Manually, by my client. He also deleted and recreated the item

Comment: This is a kinda general exception, but there is no reason for it to appear on certain items only. Are you in a web farm environment? If yes are the machine keys synchronized ? Can you try deleting your cookies and try to open the items again ?

Comment: Yes, you right. I found the issue. They were using a weird character on a multi-line text. Once I removed this character that looks like a point (.) It worked.

Comment: I am just trying to find out what is the code of this character and  I believe it came from some kind of word document which they may have copied the text from.

Comment: The problem is that if there was an error the item shouldn`t be saved :). Anyway good job at resolving it ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Content Editor was breaking was a weird character was input in a Multi-Line text field.
Probably copied from a word document.

Comment: I thought you can input any in Multi-Line text field? Irrespective of any character.

Comment: I thought the same. I don't know which character was that one. It looked like a subscribed dot. What happened, this character was breaking the JavaScript Sitecore uses to load the content editor. Even in page editor I couldn't see the character, I had to copy and paste its content to notepad to find him.